# How can an UIntPtr object be converted to IntPtr in C#?

Tags: c#, object, casting

I need to convert an `UIntPtr` object to that of `IntPtr` in my C# .NET 2.0 application.  How can this be accomplished?  I don't suppose it's as simple as this:

```
UIntPtr _myUIntPtr = /* Some initializer value. */
object _myObject = (object)_myUIntPtr;
IntPtr _myIntPtr = (IntPtr)_myObject;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work on x86 and x64

```
IntPtr intPtr = unchecked((IntPtr)(long)(ulong)uintPtr);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not appear to work on x86. I get an OverflowException with:

    `UIntPtr uintPtr = new UIntPtr(0xffffffffu);
    IntPtr intPtr = unchecked((IntPtr)(long)(ulong)uintPtr);`

Answer (score 2):

This should work on 32 bit operating systems:

```
IntPtr intPtr = (IntPtr)(int)(uint)uintPtr;
```

That is, turn the UIntPtr into a uint, turn that into an int, and then turn that into an IntPtr.

Odds are good that the jitter will optimize away all the conversions and simply turn this into a direct assignment of the one value to the other, but I haven't actually tested that.

See Jared's answer for a solution that works on 64 bit operating systems.

Comment: This is *not* okay, it destroys the pointer in 64-bit mode.  Use long/ulong.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIntPtr _myUIntPtr = /* Some initializer value. */ 
void* ptr = _myUIntPtr.ToPointer();
IntPtr _myIntPtr = new IntPtr(ptr);
```

Comment: `UIntPtr x2 = new UIntPtr(x.ToPointer());` does work, but only in an unsafe context.