# Callbacks in a DLL (Windows API)?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I need to write a library that interfaces winmm.dll.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798458(v=vs.85).aspx

```
public static class winmm {
...
   [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern uint midiInOpen(out UIntPtr lphMidiIn, uint
      uDeviceID, UIntPtr dwCallback, UIntPtr dwCallbackInstance, uint dwFlags);
...
}
```

---

```
public void MidiInOpen() {
   winmm.midiInOpen(out midiHdl, (uint)deviceId, CALLBACK, CALLBACKINSTANCE, FLAG);
}

public void midiInCallback() {
      ...
 }
```

How do I set the `dwCallback` and `dwCallbackInstance` parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `dwCallback` use a `delegate`

**Setup**

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern MMRESULT midiInOpen(out HMIDIIN lphMidiIn, UIntPtr uDeviceID,
        MidiInProc dwCallback, UIntPtr dwCallbackInstance, MidiOpenFlags dwFlags);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct HMIDIIN
{
   public IntPtr handle;
}

public enum MMRESULT : uint
{
   // General return codes.
   MMSYSERR_BASE = 0,
   MMSYSERR_NOERROR = MMSYSERR_BASE + 0,
   ...
}

public enum MidiOpenFlags : uint
{
   CALLBACK_TYPEMASK = 0x70000,
   CALLBACK_NULL = 0x00000,
   ...
}

public enum MidiInMessage : uint
{
   MIM_OPEN = 0x3C1,
   MIM_CLOSE = 0x3C2,
   ...
}
```

**Delegate**

```
public delegate void MidiInProc(HMIDIIN hMidiIn, MidiInMessage wMsg, UIntPtr dwInstance, UIntPtr dwParam1, UIntPtr dwParam2);
```

**Usage**

```
MidiInProc dwCallback ...

public static MMRESULT midiInOpen(out HMIDIIN lphMidiIn, UIntPtr uDeviceID, MidiInProc dwCallback, UIntPtr dwCallbackInstance)
{
   return midiInOpen(out lphMidiIn, uDeviceID, dwCallback, dwCallbackInstance, dwCallback == null ? MidiOpenFlags.CALLBACK_NULL : MidiOpenFlags.CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
}
```

---

Regarding `dwCallbackInstance` use [`GCHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx)

[midiInOpen function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798458(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **dwCallbackInstance** User instance data passed to the callback function. This parameter is not used with window callback functions or
>   threads.

[How To Convert Object To IntPtr And Back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339928/c-sharp-how-to-convert-object-to-intptr-and-back)

[How can an UIntPtr object be converted to IntPtr in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762113/how-can-an-uintptr-object-be-converted-to-intptr-in-c)

Just dig around, there are plenty of resources for Windows API topics

Comment: Where do I find the rest of the MidiOpenFlags, MidiInMessage, etc. values?

Comment: They can be found in the documentation, however, give me a sec

Comment: @bwoogie updated for your convenience

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind, can you post the link? I've looked everywhere..